# Change of code is causing options in drop down menu to not appear

Tags: php, mysqli

Ok if you look at the editsessionteacher.php script, it contained the code below which worked whne it comes to displaying the values below in a drop down menu:

```
$outputmodule = ""; 

        $moduleInfo = explode("_", $_POST['modules']);
        $moduleId = $moduleInfo[0];
        $moduleName = $moduleInfo[1];
        $outputmodule = sprintf("<p><strong>Module:</strong> %s - %s</p>", $moduleId, $moduleName);
```

The module.php was this:

```
$course = isset($_POST['course']) ? $_POST['course'] : ''; 

$sql = "
SELECT cm.CourseId, cm.ModuleId,
c.CourseName,
m.ModuleName
FROM Course c
INNER JOIN Course_Module cm ON c.CourseId = cm.CourseId
JOIN Module m ON cm.ModuleId = m.ModuleId
WHERE
(c.CourseId = ?)
ORDER BY c.CourseId, m.ModuleId
"; 

 $sqlstmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

 $sqlstmt->bind_param("s",$course);

 $sqlstmt->execute(); 

 $sqlstmt->bind_result($dbCourseId,$dbModuleId,$dbCourseName,$dbModuleName);


$moduleHTML  = "";  

     while($sqlstmt->fetch()) { 
         $moduleHTML .= sprintf('<option value="%1$s_%2$s">%1$s - %2$s</option>'.PHP_EOL, $dbModuleId, $dbModuleName);
    } 


echo $moduleHTML; 

 $sqlstmt->execute();
```

**EDIT:**

But I want to add the moduleNo into the drop down menu, so when I tried to change the code to this below, it doesn't work:

editsessionteacher.php:

```
     $sql = "SELECT CourseId, CourseNo, CourseName FROM Course"; 

 $sqlstmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

 $sqlstmt->execute(); 

 $sqlstmt->bind_result($dbCourseId, $dbCourseNo, $dbCourseName);

 $courses = array(); // easier if you don't use generic names for data 

 $courseHTML = "";  
 $courseHTML .= '<select name="courses" id="coursesDrop" onchange="getModules();">'.PHP_EOL; 
 $courseHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  

 while($sqlstmt->fetch()) 
 { 
     $courseno = $dbCourseNo;
     $course = $dbCourseId;
     $coursename = $dbCourseName; 
     $courseHTML .= "<option value='".$course."'>" . $courseno . " - " . $coursename . "</option>".PHP_EOL;  
  } 

  $courseHTML .= '</select>'; 

    $moduleHTML = "";  
    $moduleHTML .= '<select name="modules" id="modulesDrop">'.PHP_EOL; 
    $moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  
    $moduleHTML .= '</select>'; 


    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function getModules() { 
    var course = jQuery("#coursesDrop").val(); 
    jQuery('#modulesDrop').empty(); 
    jQuery('#modulesDrop').html('<option value="">Please Select</option>'); 
    jQuery.ajax({ 
    type: "post", 
    url:  "module.php", 
    data: { course:course }, 
    success: function(response){ 
    jQuery('#modulesDrop').append(response); 
    } 
    }); 


    }


    </script> 


<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validation();">
<table>
<tr>
<th>Course: <?php echo $courseHTML; ?></th>
<th>Module: <?php echo $moduleHTML; ?></th>
</tr>
</table>
<p><input id="moduleSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit Course and Module" name="moduleSubmit" /></p>
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['moduleSubmit'])) {    

$outputmodule = ""; 

$moduleInfo = explode("_", $_POST['modules']);
$moduleId = $moduleInfo[0];
$moduleNo = $moduleInfo[1];
$moduleName = $moduleInfo[2];
$outputmodule = sprintf("<p><strong>Module:</strong> %s - %s</p>", $moduleNo, $moduleName);


....
```

module.php:

```
    $course = isset($_POST['course']) ? $_POST['course'] : ''; 

    $sql = "
    SELECT cm.CourseId, cm.ModuleId, c.CourseNo, m.ModuleNo,
    c.CourseName,
    m.ModuleName
    FROM Course c
    INNER JOIN Course_Module cm ON c.CourseId = cm.CourseId
    JOIN Module m ON cm.ModuleId = m.ModuleId
    WHERE
    (c.CourseId = ?)
    ORDER BY c.CourseId, m.ModuleId
    "; 

     $sqlstmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

     $sqlstmt->bind_param("s",$course);

     $sqlstmt->execute(); 

     $sqlstmt->bind_result($dbCourseId,$dbModuleId,$dbCourseNo,$dbModuleNo,$dbCourseName,$dbModuleName);


    $moduleHTML  = "";  

$moduleHTML .= '<select name="modules" id="modulesDrop">'.PHP_EOL; 
$moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  

 while($sqlstmt->fetch()) { 
     $moduleHTML .= sprintf('<option value="%1$s">%2$s - %3$s</option>'.PHP_EOL, $dbModuleId, $dbModuleNo, $dbModuleName);
} 

$moduleHTML .= '</select>'; 

echo $moduleHTML;
```

My question is that why is it not displaying anything in the drop down menu when I changed the code to add the Module Number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why your drop down menu is not displaying, but I do see an issue with your modified `module.php` `sprintf()` and how it will display in your `editsessionteacher.php`.

The original `module.php` `sprintf()` passed 2 values concatenated using '_'

```
$moduleHTML .= sprintf('<option value="%1$s_%2$s">%1$s - %2$s</option>'.PHP_EOL, $dbModuleId, $dbModuleName);
                                       ---------
```

and your `editsessionteacher.php` `explode()` those 2 values

```
$moduleInfo = explode("_", $_POST['modules']);
$moduleId = $moduleInfo[0];
$moduleName = $moduleInfo[1];
```

but your modified `module.php` `sprintf()` is only passing 1 value -

```
$moduleHTML .= sprintf('<option value="%1$s">%2$s - %3$s</option>'.PHP_EOL, $dbModuleId, $dbModuleNo, $dbModuleName);
                                      -----
```

but your `editsessionteacher.php` is trying to `explode()` 3 values

```
$moduleInfo = explode("_", $_POST['modules']);
$moduleId = $moduleInfo[0];
$moduleNo = $moduleInfo[1];
$moduleName = $moduleInfo[2];
```

So based off your `editsessionteacher.php` `explode()`, try updating your `module.php` `sprintf()` to -

```
$moduleHTML .= sprintf('<option value="%1$s_%2$s_%3$s">%2$s - %3$s</option>'.PHP_EOL, $dbModuleId, $dbModuleNo, $dbModuleName);
                                       --------------
```

Comment: Are you sure that your query is returning any rows? Have you tried running your query in phpMyAdmin? You could also add a `$sqlstmt->num_rows` check with `if ($sqlstmt->num_rows >0 ){ while($sqlstmt->fetch()) { $moduleHTML .= sprintf('<option value="%1$s">%2$s - %3$s</option>'.PHP_EOL, $dbModuleId, $dbModuleNo, $dbModuleName);
} } else { echo"NO ROWS RETURNED";}`

Comment: So your `<select name="modules" id="modulesDrop"></select>` in `modules.php` is empty with 0 `<option></option>`'s ?

Comment: I tired to echo the $course variable but nothing is outputting, could this be the reason?

Comment: I have figured it out, thanks for your help anyway. Still mark the answer